# DB2 Export command export invalid date

Tags: db2, export

I am using Db2 database for my project. I want to export the data from local to server.
So I have used the export command to get the data.

```
export to '/home/user/user.sql' of del select * from user
```

This works fine. But the date format of datas will be wrong in user.sql file like below.

```
1,"user1",20110606

2,"user2",20110607
```

Here 20110606 is a date format. It exported the format like this instead of 2011-06-06

Because of this problem, when I Load the data into server, the date fields are stored as NULL.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is normal for how DB2 exports data stored in a DATE column.  When you use the IMPORT or LOAD command it will automatically parse this data assuming its YYYYMMDD.  If you are getting an error with this, please post the actual LOAD or IMPORT statement you are executing and the specific error you get.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde - There might be problems if it thinks the date data is numeric - the normal conversion would be _number of days_ since 0001-01-01; the given 'number of days' puts it in the year 55061 - out-of-range.  This likely needs to be exported/imported as `CHAR`.

Comment: @X-Zero The DB2 utilities by themselves won't have any issues, as long as you're dealing the actual DATE columns.  With third party tools, or non-DATE columns, YMMV.  Thus, my request for more information from the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you can try.

The [EXPORT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html) command has a timestampformat parameter that can format timestamps on the way out. Your command will look something like:

```
export to '/home/user/user.sql' of del 
modified by timestampformat="YYYY-MM-DD" select * from user
```

OR you can use some of db2's built in formatting functions to format the column in the select statement (for example [CHAR](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000777.html) or [TIMESTAMPFORMAT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html)). Something like this:

```
export to '/home/user/user.sql' of del 
select col1, col2...char(date_col) from user
```

Comment: The expression `modified by timestampformat` only applies to TIMESTAMP columns – not DATE columns.

Comment: Thanks.. It works fine for timestamp format. Is there any option for date also?

Comment: If you follow the links I provided you should be able to see all the options for the EXPORT command and for formatting dates.